# Code style defining multiple constants in PHP

Tags: php, constants, class-constants

Is there any significant difference in how I define multiple constants in PHP class between:

this:

```
<?php
abstract class Some_Class
{
    const CONSTANT_ONE   = 101;
    const CONSTANT_TWO   = 102;
    const CONSTANT_THREE = 103;
}
```

and probably closer to JS style of defining:

```
<?php
abstract class Some_Class
{
    const CONSTANT_ONE   = 101,
          CONSTANT_TWO   = 102,
          CONSTANT_THREE = 103
    ;
}
```

Comment: There is no practical difference whatsoever except the obviously different syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding syntax there is no difference.

Even the [PHP-FIG Standards concerning constants](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#63-constant-or-property) allows the use of the second form documentation-wise (they call it compound statements).

Personally I prefer the first form :)

```
abstract class Some_Class {
    /**
     * @var int CONSTANT_ONE This constant is magical
     */
    const CONSTANT_ONE   = 101;

    /**
     * @var float CONSTANT_TWO This is Pi!
     */
    const CONSTANT_TWO   = 3.14;

    /**
     * @var string CONSTANT_THREE The magical door number
     */
    const CONSTANT_THREE = "103a";
}
```